# Using RazorPay SDK - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am using `Cordova` to build my iOS app. I have a plugin 'Razorpay-Cordova' which is giving the following error

[image]

Not sure why am I getting this error at the time of Build.
Tried many solutions in internet, not able to solve.

PS: Project is running successfully in another MAC. I am facing issue in my machine.

Cordova Verison : 6.0

Ionic Version : 1.7

Xcode version 8.1.

Comment: Make sure to add the Security framework:

#import <Security/SecRandom.h>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the frameworks `Security` and `CoreTelephony` to your project.

Just add them under your Target > Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries.
No need of any import statements.

Disclaimer: I am a developer at Razorpay.

Comment: Also someone, please add razorpay tag . I do not have enough reputation. That will be helpful for easy findings in future

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Security Framework to your project.

```
#import <Security/SecRandom.h>
```